# Simplify nested If into a loop

Tags: functions, conditional, expression-test

I would like to simplify a set of tests (meant to be applied on a random set of parameters), written for now as nested If:

```
Tableinit = {{"a", "b"}};
c = {1.8, 1.3, 2.5};
Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 2}]}]; 
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 If[a > c[[1]] /. testP, 
  If[a > c[[2]] /. testP, 
   If[a > c[[3]] /. testP, Print["yaha"], Continue[]], Continue[]], 
  Continue[]], {3}]
```

So that I get for example:

```
{1.89136,0.143095}
{2.98853,1.98695}
yaha
{1.93,0.424178}
```

into a loop. The closest I got was:

```
Tableinit = {{"a", "b"}};
c = {1.8, 1.3, 2.5};
Do[Print[set = {RandomReal[{0, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 2}]}]; 
 testP = {a -> set[[1]], b -> set[[2]]};
 Do[If[a > c[[i]] /. testP, Print["yaha"], Break[]], {i, 3}], {3}]
```

But as expected I get:

```
{1.89136,0.143095}
{2.98853,1.98695}
yaha
yaha
yaha
{1.93,0.424178}
yaha
```

Instead of getting "yaha" only when the 3 conditions are fulfilled.

How could I write it? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you know that `&&` does short-circuit evaluation? Use that to convert to a single `If[]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange, and thanks for taking the time to format your question properly.

Comment: Yes but the good thing about If [.. , .. , Continue[]] is that it will stop the calculations from the 1st condition that is not fulfilled. Won't it calculate all of them within the unique If with &&?

Comment: "Won't it calculate all of them" - I suggest then that you look up what short-circuit evaluation means.

Comment: Haha ok thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If[And @@ Thread[a > c /. testP], Print["yaha"]]
```

Comment: Equivalently: `And @@ Thread[a > c /. testP] && Print["yaha"];`

Comment: This will evaluate all three conditions as opposed to stopping at the first condition that fails.